# Use JavaScript to write HTML element attribute text into HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

How do I target `message` using JavaScript here to write to the  tag? Here is my HTML code:

```html
<h1 message = "this is the title of the page"></h1>
```

The `message` should only show in certain circumstances. Just wondering how I would use JavaScript to grab that element and inject its contents into the h1 tag when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it as below. Feel free to adapt it to your use case, as for now, it will write into the `<h1>` as soon as the script is loaded and gets executed.

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
h1.textContent = h1.getAttribute("message");
```

```html
<h1 message = "this is the title of the page"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getAttribute` method is used to `get` the value of any attribute in html tag.

Syntax of using `getAttribute`

`element.getAttribute (attributename);`

```js
const target = document.querySelector("h1");
// Original attribute
console.log(target.getAttribute("message"))
```

```html
<h1 message="I am message in h1 tag"></h1>
```

`setAttribute` method is used to `set` the value of any attribute in html tag.

Syntax of using `setAttribute`

`element.setAttribute(attributename, attributevalue);`

```js
const target = document.querySelector("h1");
// Original attribute
console.log(target.getAttribute("message"))

// changed attribute
target.setAttribute("message","message attribute changed") 
console.log(target.getAttribute("message"))
```

```html
<h1 message = "this is the title of the page"></h1>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569107/use-javascript-to-write-text-into-html-interface#
```